# How to load an image in Dart

Tags: dart

I'm trying out the Dart Language and HTML5 Canvas element, but I'm stuck with one problem. I don't know how to load an image in Dart. I can get CanvasRenderingContext2D and with this I can call fillText() and fillRect() and everything works, but I am trying to figure out how to load an Image and draw with drawImage.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create and load the image

```dart
ImageElement image = new ImageElement(src: "my_image.png");
image.onLoad.listen((e) {
    // Draw once the image is loaded
});
```

Draw the above image on the canvas after it is loaded

```dart
context.drawImage(image, destX, destY);
```

Comment: Hi, I'm new to dart and when I try the image.on.load.add function I get an error stating that "load" is not a member of Events. Also the code hinting isn't very helpful with this. I'm using Dart Editor version 0.4.2_r20259 and Dart SDK version 0.4.2.8_r20259.

Comment: Ok, I found out why: the dartlang core had an update... [Dart News & Updates](http://news.dartlang.org/2013/01/new-dom-event-streams-api.html). Now "image.on.load.add" should be written as "image.onLoad.listen".

Comment: Since M1 of Dart was released the syntax has changed add "src:" before the filename ( new ImageElement(src:"my_image.png"); ) or this will cause a runtime error.

Answer (score 9):

Newer image onload syntax:

```dart
readFile() {
    ImageElement image = new ImageElement(src: "plant.png");
    document.body.nodes.add(image);
    image.onLoad.listen(onData, onError: onError, onDone: onDone, cancelOnError: true);
  }

  onData(Event e) {
    print("success: ");
  }

  onError(Event e) {
    print("error: $e");
  }

  onDone() {
    print("done");
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is another way to do it :

```dart
void main() {
  ImageElement image = new ImageElement(src: "pic.png");
  img.onLoad.listen(onData);
  img.onError.listen(onError);
}

void onData(Event e) {
  print("Load success");
}

void onError(Event e) {
  print("Error: $e");
}
```