# How to work with Images in Dart lang

Tags: dart

I'm post a question here before( [How to load an image in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599113/dart-lang-how-to-load-image) ) and get answer, but same time get more questions.
Why I'm can draw image only this way:

```dart
image.on.load.add((e) {
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
});
```

but if I'm write something like:

```dart
ImageElement image = new ImageElement();
image.src = 'myImage.png';
context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
```

^^^ this don't work and don't draw image. Why?

```dart
bool loaded = false;
ImageElement image = new ImageElement();
image.src = 'myImage.png';
image.on.load.add((e) {
    loaded = true;
});
print(loaded); // on console get - false
```

^^^ why I'm get false? I'm created if image loaded variable loaded become true, but loaded don't become true.

Sorry for my bad English language. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

As for your first question, if you leave out

```dart
image.onLoad.listen((e) {
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
});
```

then no code will be executed when the image is loaded.

The **on.load.add(...)** construction basically assigns a function (often referred to as a handler) that will be executed when the browser loads the image. If no such function is assigned then nothing happens when the image is loaded and consequently **context.drawImage(image, 0, 0)** will not work.

Your second questions is related to this function. Loading an image is an asynchronous process, meaning your on load handler (**on.load.add(...)**) is first fired when the client has successfully loaded the image. This means that after assininging your on load handler execution continues to your next call: **print(loaded)** which will be false as the image is not loaded yet.

Answer (score 5):

Newer image onload syntax:

```dart
readFile() {
  ImageElement image = new ImageElement(src: "plant.png");
  document.body.nodes.add(image);
  image.onLoad.listen(
      onData, 
      onError: onError, 
      onDone: onDone, 
      cancelOnError: true
   );
}

onData(Event e) {
  print("success");
}

onError(Event e) {
  print("error: $e");
}

onDone() {
  print("done");
}
```