# How do you load an Image server side in dart?

Tags: dart

I've seen the answers for using an [ImageElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599113/how-to-load-an-image-in-dart) to load an image.  This only works on the browser side and I wanted to do some processing on the server.

Is there any way to load and read RGBA values from a PNG in server side dart?  If not are there any server side image processing libraries planned?

Is there anyway to run Dartium "headless" so I can use the canvas api to do what I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a dart library that can read and write PNG images server side,
http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image

The library can read and write PNG and JPG images, and provides a number of image manipulation commands.

For example, to read a PNG, resize it, and save it to disk using this library:

```
import 'dart:io' as Io;
import 'package:image/image.dart';
void main() {
    // Read a PNG image from file.
    Image image = readPng(new Io.File('foo.png').readAsBytesSync());

    // Resize the image to a 120x? thumbnail (maintaining the aspect ratio).
    Image thumbnail = copyResize(image, 120);

    // Save the thumbnail to disk as a PNG.
    new Io.File('foo-thumbnail.png').writeAsBytesSync(writePng(thumbnail));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no library out there at the moment.

I have been using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) instead. You could use [`Process.run()`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_io/Process.html#run) to run it. Here's an example:

```dart
Process.run('/usr/local/bin/convert', ['file', '-resize', '100x100']);
```

Comment: Yeah I was hoping for a pure Dart way of doing it, most likely with headless Dartium.  But this does answer the initial question.

Comment: If something comes up, I'll update my answer. I'd also like to see a library for manipulating images. I've considered working on one, but I fear I don't have enough time for that.

Comment: Right even though its still a valid answer looking more into doing with via ImageMagick's CLI there doesn't appear to be a way to do per pixel value reads.  At that rate might as well keep my current java version and just call it directly.

Comment: Might want to check out https://github.com/Serabe/RMagick4J/tree/master/Magick4J/src/magick4j